# why my collapse default is not hidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
    var item = this.props.data
    return (
        <li key={item.id} className="faq-item-li" id={"faq-item-li-" + item.counter}>
            <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-target={"#answer"+ item.id} >{item.title}</h4>
            <div id={"answer"+ item.id} class="collapse">{item.description}</div>
        </li>
    );
}
```

`div` part default is always shown. I want this part to be hidden first

Comment: there is no distinguishable way that we can help answer this question. you may need to take a look at the help center to find out how to ask a question

Comment: Please provide all your react component code, because without knowing all code and data that is passed it is not possible to get what you are asking. Thanks

Comment: above comments are useless. Please carefully read my code first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `class='collapse'` by `className='collapse'`